# How do i fix this error message Warning: move_uploaded_file() expects parameter 1 to be string

Tags: php, html, jquery

I am new to PHP and I got a project that has to do with classified ads website.. now I want if any users upload images no matter the dimension or size it should resize to 750x450 I got the code below which worked for me but got the above error.

The question is how do I resize the image and return the extension as .png without having any errors using the format below to help me improve.

// The form...

```
<div class="dashboard-wrapper">
<p>Browse image files to upload for the Ad <b><?php echo $ad_title; ?></b><br>All images must have a dimension of <strong>(750 X 450)</strong></p>
<?php require 'constants/check_reply.php'; ?>
<form action="app/send-image.php" method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input   accept="image/*"   type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" required name="image" /><br><br>
   <input type="hidden" name="uploadlink" value="<?php echo $add_id; ?>">
   <img id="blah"class="image-preview" src="../assets/img/blank.png" alt="Image Preview" /><br><br>
   <button class="btn btn-common" name="submit" type="submit">Upload</button>
   <script>
      function readURL(input) {
                if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
      
                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                        $('#blah')
                            .attr('src', e.target.result);
                    };
      
                    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
                }
            }
          
   </script>
</form>
```

// send-image.php ...

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    if (is_array($_FILES))
    {
        $id = $_POST['uploadlink'];
        $upload_link = '../../uploads/ads/' . $id . '/';
        $target_dir = "../../uploads/avatar/";
        $file = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
        $data = getimagesize($file);
        $new_file_name = '' . $id . '' . date('dmYhis') . '';
        $target_file = '../../uploads/ads/' . $id . '/' . $new_file_name . '';
        $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

        $imageType = $data[2];

        switch ($imageType)
        {
            case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
                $imageResourceId = imagecreatefrompng($file);
                $targetLayer = imageResize($imageResourceId, $data[0], $data[1]);
                imagepng($targetLayer, $target_file . $ext);
            break;
            case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
                $imageResourceId = imagecreatefromgif($file);
                $targetLayer = imageResize($imageResourceId, $data[0], $data[1]);
                imagegif($targetLayer, $target_file . $ext);
            break;
            case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
                $imageResourceId = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
                $targetLayer = imageResize($imageResourceId, $data[0], $data[1]);
                imagejpeg($targetLayer, $target_file . $ext);
            break;
            default:
                echo "Invalid Image type.";
                exit;
            break;
        }
        move_uploaded_file($targetLayer, $target_file . $ext);
        echo "Image Resize Successfully.";
    }
}

function imageResize($imageResourceId, $width, $height)
{
    $targetWidth = 750;
    $targetHeight = 450;

    $targetLayer = imagecreatetruecolor($targetWidth, $targetHeight);

    imagecopyresampled($targetLayer, $imageResourceId, 0, 0, 0, 0, $targetWidth, $targetHeight, $width, $height);

    return $targetLayer;
}
?>
```

Comment: did you try move_uploaded_file($targetLayer,$target_file.'.'.$ext) - your var $ext is only holding the extension without a preceding period. Same here imagepng($targetLayer,$target_file.'.'.$ext); etc..

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatetruecolor.php - this function returns a resource identifier, not a string.

Comment: I get the error below when i try this $targetLayer,$target_file.'.'.$ext... Warning: imagejpeg(../../uploads/ads/AD33697047/AD3369704704102020091013.): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\xampp\htdocs\market\user\app\send-image.php on line 55

Warning: move_uploaded_file() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in C:\xampp\htdocs\market\user\app\send-image.php on line 71
Image Resize Successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are moving resourceId and not file.
First move uploded file and that work with it.

```
// after $file = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]; put this code:
$tmp = './tmp_path/'.$_FILES['image']['name'];
move_uploaded_file($file, $tmp);
$file = $tmp;
```

// comment line: move_uploaded_file($targetLayer, $target_file.$ext);

Comment: how do i make the image retain this ../../uploads/ads/AD33697047/AD3369704704102020091013 with extension .png on the directory created automatically with user unique id....

Comment: $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_ads (ad_id, author, title, category, city, ad_condition, price, short_desc, fixed, brand, description, date_posted) VALUES (:adid, :author, :title, :category, :city, :adcond, :price, :shortdesc, :fixed, :brand, :description, :datepost)");

Comment: $stmt->bindParam(':adid', $ad_id);
    $stmt->bindParam(':author', $myid);
    $stmt->bindParam(':title', $ad_title);
    $stmt->bindParam(':category', $ad_category);
    $stmt->bindParam(':city', $ad_city);
    $stmt->bindParam(':adcond', $condition);
    $stmt->bindParam(':price', $price);
    $stmt->bindParam(':shortdesc', $short_desc);

Comment: $stmt->bindParam(':fixed', $fixed);
    $stmt->bindParam(':brand', $brand);
    $stmt->bindParam(':description', $desc);
    $stmt->bindParam(':datepost', $datepost);
    mkdir("../../uploads/ads/$ad_id");
    header("location:../ad-images?node=$ad_id");

Comment: My code is just example to right way, because you misunderstand base functionality of uploading and manipulation files. As I described : 1. move uploaded tmp file into some your tmp path with uploaded filename. 2. process moved file as you need. Its very very simple. don't be afraid of it.

Comment: Thank you so much let me put this to practice and see... i will update when am done

Comment: Good day sir, Thanks for being so nice to me.. i want to ask you one more question please don't get offended. am still new to PHP that why i ask so many questions.. I followed your steps and now i can upload to the directory. the questioned is why do i still get the below errors. Warning: move_uploaded_file() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in C:\xampp\htdocs\market\user\app\send-image.php on line 76
Image Resize Successfully. even after it was successfully uploaded.

Comment: comment your line: move_uploaded_file($targetLayer, $target_file.$ext);, because $targetLayer is "resource id" and not file. Resource id is some identifier created by imagecreatetruecolor. Its not file and its impossible manipulate with it.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked... i sincerely appreciate... you are a life saver. you just saved me...

Comment: you're welcome. Mark my answer as useful and accepted.